# An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the GetSecretValue operation: The security token included in the request is invalid

Tags: python, boto3, aws-sam

Please check below is the screenshot it is having problem. Aws credentials are configured correctly and its working fine when we use separately in boto3 but in SAM lambda function trigger it getting this error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kk3C.png)

tried with all solutions like checking "aws configure" & unset `AWS_SECURITY_TOKEN` & other solutions mentioned in other sources also tried but didn't work.

and In code am trying to do

```
session = boto3.session.Session()
secretsmanager = session.client('secretsmanager')

try:
        get_secret_value_response = secretsmanager.get_secret_value(
            SecretId=secret_name
        )
        secret = json.loads(get_secret_value_response['SecretString'])
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e)
        # print(sys.exc_info(),traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout))
    except Exception as e:
        print(sys.exc_info(),traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout))
        print(e)
```

Comment: Double check your IAM credentials used for your program. Are you sure they are still valid?

Answer (score 5):

Remove AWS credentials by deleting this file `~/.aws/credentials`. Then re-run `aws configure` and pass valid security credentials. This should fix the issue that you are encountering.

If you have multiple profiles configured then edit `~/.aws/credentials` and remove the profile that was used with this code.For example if you have used user1 while configuring the credentials then your file will have contents similar to below:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAIOSFODNN7EXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=wJalrXUtnFEMI/K7MDENG/bPxRfiCYEXAMPLEKEY

[user1]
aws_access_key_id=AKIAI44QH8DHBEXAMPLE
aws_secret_access_key=je7MtGbClwBF/2Zp9Utk/h3yCo8nvbEXAMPLEKEY
```

To solve this issue simply delete [user1] section from `~/.aws/credentials` then re-run `aws configure` .

Comment: Hi. What if in the file there are multiple profiles? Deleting the file will delete everything leading to more issues.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe is a little different problem but I got the exactly same error locally because I set the default profile before getting the session.

So, if I run the script with:

```
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='myprofile')
session = boto3.session.Session()
secretsmanager = session.client('secretsmanager')
```

I got the same error as the question, probably because they didn't works well when used together.

To solve, you can just remove the session part:

```
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='myprofile')
secretsmanager = boto3.client('secretsmanager')
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it wasn't working because I was missing the session token. I added the token in the boto3 Session and it worked:

```
session = boto3.session.Session(
    aws_access_key_id=AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key=AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_session_token=AWS_SESSION_TOKEN,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to deleting credentials file and running ***aws configure*** again, you can also run this in your terminal

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=your-access-key-id

export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=your-secret-access-key
```